# ISO 8601 DateTimeFormatter truncates the ms of this format:'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, zoneddatetime, datetimeformatter

An online API is requiring this format:

```
string

completion formatted as ISO 8601 timestamp - 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'
2018-11-21T22:38:15.000Z
```

I am trying to get any LocalDate at noon to satisfy the requirement, however, when Java looks at Noon or the start of day, it truncates the subseconds. For example:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME
                    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                    .format(LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalTime.NOON).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC))
```

produces:

`2021-03-08T12:00:00Z`

The api needs the subseconds. Is there a way for me to force the precision?

I tried building one:

`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")`
but the Z is missing from the output.

Comment: `s` is still seconds, not milliseconds just because you put it after the dot. Did you mean `SSS`?

Comment: In Java, yes, but they are saying milliseconds.

Comment: Updated my comment, I guess it's clearer now

Comment: I am using the built in formatter for ISO_DATE_TIME. It works on any other time.

Comment: Well, you could always provide your own time format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of your own `DateTimeFormatter`:

```java
private static final DateTimeFormatter DTF = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
```

And then use that to format your date:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalTime.NOON).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
String formatted = DTF.format(zdt);
System.out.println(formatted); // 2021-03-08T12:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: I did try creating one... but yours uses a lower case Z ... it may solve my problem ... I'll try

Comment: Can you explain what the difference between z and X ?

Comment: @trilogy in your case it doesn't really make a difference. `z` prints the time zone name, whereas `X` will use values like `-08; -0830; -08:30;`, with the exception of UTC where it simply prints `Z` instead

Comment: We should use 'u' instead of 'y' as well?

Comment: @trilogy You shouldn't care about `u`, unless you work with dates before the year `0`

Comment: z resulted in Z not GMT.... both worked in this case.

Comment: @user15244370 – GMT? Or Europe/London (or something similar that has currently +00:00 off set to UTC)?

Comment: @user15244370 – Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303580/understanding-the-etc-gmt-time-zone, first answer … you are on Etc/GMT time zone, not on GMT ...

Answer (score 1):

What about using your own format instead of ISO_DATE_TIME?

Have look to [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) on how to build your own format with the required precision.

And by the way, the format you use does not truncate "the last 0", is just does not show the milliseconds ...

Comment: I tried building one, but the Z is missing `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` it provides an Offset of +00 instead

Comment: The "Z" is the time zone ("Zulu Time" or UTC). And do not use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()`, use the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` …

Comment: I know what Z means.. but the api specifically wants the Z in the output.  It is a UTC date.

Comment: @tquadrat why shouldn't you use the `ofPattern` method? What is the advantage of using the builder?

Comment: @Lino – The builder gives you more control, what is helpful in *this* case. But in general you can also use the `ofPattern()` method when you are sure about the pattern. In particular with the time zone stuff, the pattern is … difficult sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

### No worries

`LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` have nanosecond precision always. So the milliseconds are not gone, they are just zero. And are not printed from `toString()` when they are zero.

Edit: I understand from your comment that the following paragraph does not apply to your situation. I am letting it stand for others to whom it may be useful. You most probably do not need to worry. Your API needs ISO 8601 format. In ISO 8601 the milliseconds (and smaller) are optional when they are zero. Most APIs that accept ISO 8601 (and all that I have met), also accept the string without the milliseconds.

### Links

Related questions:

- [java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-02-19T00:45:09.798Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23 [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66442927/java-time-format-datetimeparseexception-text-2021-02-19t004509-798z-could-n) on pattern letter `Z`
- [String to ZonedDateTime is changing format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120213/string-to-zoneddatetime-is-changing-format)

And the central link:

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: I did look at the Wiki article. I first thought the company wasn't following ISO 8601 by forcing the issue, but then I read in there: "However, the number of decimal places needs to be agreed to by the communicating parties. " ...  The API rejected anything less than 3 decimal places...