# How parse specific format with Joda TIme (JAVA 6)

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, jodatime

I need to parse specific date with joda library, I cant use an other library because its java 6 and we dont have another library available in module.

Anyway, I have this date :

2022-08-02T23:00:59Z

And I need to parse it for some operation after, but when I try to parse, I have this error :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2022-08-02T23:00:59Z" is malformed at "Z"

My code :

```
 String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
        String dateString="2022-08-02T23:00:59Z";
        DateTimeFormatter date = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
        DateTime dateTIme = date.parseDateTime(dateString);
```

Maybe I make something wrong ?

I cannot found the good format for this pattern, so if anyone has idea, thank you very much

Comment: Hello, try "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"

Comment: Similar: [java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-02-19T00:45:09.798Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66442927/java-time-format-datetimeparseexception-text-2021-02-19t004509-798z-could-n). That question is about java.time, not Joda-Tme; but the problem is the same and the solution similar.

Comment: @Mar-Z No, incorrect. **Never put the `Z` within quotes.** The quotes mean "expect but ignore this text". You will be ignoring vital information, the offset from UTC (a number of hours-minutes-seconds).

Comment: Totally agree. I realized it later...

Answer (score 2):

No need to define a formatting pattern at all. Your input text conforms to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats used by default in [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse( "2022-08-02T23:00:59Z" );
```

Generate text from that date-time object, in ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = dt.toString();
```

> 2022-08-02T23:00:59.000Z

---

As for what is wrong with your formatting pattern: Your pattern accounts for 3 parts (date, `T` delimiter, time). But your input has 4 parts, those 3 plus an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), the number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the temporal meridian of UTC. The character `Z` is an abbreviation of `+00:00`, for an offset of zero.

---

> I cant use an other library because its java 6 and we dont have another library available in module

FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library is now in maintenance-mode. Its creator went on to also create its successor, the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 and bundled with Java 8+. A back-port of those classes was made to support earlier Java 6 and Java 7. See the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

I recommend using that back-port rather than Joda-Time. The API of *ThreeTen-Backport* is nearly identical to *java.time*. This makes eventual migration to *java.time* quite simple, little more than changing `import` statements.

And of course, [Java 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_6) is very much past end-of-life.